# How to implement example.com/username

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

How do websites deal with:

`example.com/username`?

For example if you have a page called "about", `example.com/about`, and a user signs up with the username `about`, what happens? Someone trying to access `example.com/about` will be sent to either the user's page or the about page, depending on the configuration.

Do websites simply forbid usernames of existing pages like `about`, `index`, etc? What happens if the website wants to add a new page like `help`, and a user has already signed up with that name?

Here's a rule I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

And excluding reserved URIs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!index|upload|foo|bar).+) user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Then in my application, disallow the names `index, upload, foo, bar, ...`.

What's the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: Use a virtual path for user profiles like `example.com/u/john`, `example.com/u/bob` etc

Comment: Do not use the same URL scheme for your pages as you do for your profile pages and yes you can create a reservation filter php file to prevent certain words being used. Don't use htaccess for this. I have done this before.